# I need help connecting jsdelivr and webflow

Tags: cdn, webflow, jsdelivr

I am hosting my JS on github and attempting to execute this code on my front end webflow (Webflow has a 10,000 character limit on the custom code). I want to execute my github code on webflow, and I've followed the steps from jsdeliver, but no luck. Any suggestions? Here is my code

"<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/mason-waters1/sportology@main/HSFBRecruitPageHeader> "

I thought that if I hosted my code on github, plugged the file path into the jsdelivr format, then pasted that into webflow, that my code would execute.